# How do i insert data into database using DAO method through spring controller?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have clientDAO interface and clientDaoImpl class; I declared method in clientDAO  and define method in clientDaoImpl. I also define mysql database connection in spring-servlet.xml ( which is spring-config file) as data source.

```
import java.util.Date;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@SessionAttributes
@Controller 
public class clientRegistrationController {
@Autowired
private clientDAO clientdao;
     @SessionAttributes
    @Controller 
    public class ClientRegistrationController {


    @RequestMapping( value="/registration",method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public @ResponseBody  
       String client_registration(@RequestParam(value = "date_of_registration") Date date_of_registration)

      // here i want to get pojo object and call method insert method which is 
      // defined in DAO implement class.
                return " Registered successfully";    

        }
@RequestMapping("/registration")
    public ModelAndView showContacts() {
    String message = "Hello World, Spring MVC @ Javatpoint";
        return new ModelAndView("client_registration", "message",message);
    }
}
```

I got following error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet [spring] in web application [/SpringTiles] threw load() exception
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Autowired cannot be resolved to a type
    clientDAO cannot be resolved to a type
```

I used /SpringTiles code available in [javatpoint.com](https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-mvc-tiles-example)
this is my clientdao:

package dao;

```
import com.javatpoint.form.Client_Registration;

public interface clientDAO {
void insertData(Client_Registration patient);
}
```

Comment: Show us your class clientDAO

Comment: there is context:component-scan for controller package and how do i create bean ?

Comment: You should include package of your clientDAO into component-scan

Answer (score 0):

This exception comes when there is no any bean created of mentioned type.
Make sure you have added context:component-scan tag in your spring-servlet.xml file.
e.g.

and also check whether you have added @Repository annotation on Dao

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have added @Repository on your clientDAO class. Spring is not able to find it at the load time. 
Check your configurations (xml or java) whichever you have used for bean creation. 
sharing Full error logs along with relevant snippet of code( here clientDAO and configuration) helps in faster error resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You should inject you DAO like that :

```
<bean id="dao" class="com.elgarnaoui.ma.dao.AgentDao"></bean>
    <bean id="metier" class="com.elgarnaoui.ma.metier.MetierAgent">
        <property name="dao" ref="dao"></property>
    </bean>
```